# cakePHP Passing values back to original view after saving failure

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm working on a CakePHP project from a previous developer, this is really my first time doing anything on cakePHP. This is what I'm struggling with, I'm trying to set an add view that requires many fields to be filled with data. After "saving" the data on the view, It should let you save unless there are some missing fields (due to the sql insert). What I'm stuck is where I try to redirect back to the same page (after error) and pass the previous data that was entered back to the add view.

My other problem is that if that after I do a redirect to add/0, it doesn't work it just goes to add/ which gives me errors if I don't handle null value.

This is some of my code.

```php
PresupuestosController.php
     function add( $cliente_id = 0 )
        {
          .... some code
   if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
       $request = $this->request->data;
      ... some more code

      if ( $this->Presupuesto->save( $presupuesto ) ) {
           //here i'm getting most of my errors where PresupuestoDetalle is not 'defined' so I get errors of missing fields.


           foreach ( $request['PresupuestoDetalle'] as $articulo ) {
                            $presupuesto_detalle = $this->PresupuestoDetalle->create();
                            $presupuesto_detalle['presupuesto_id'] = $this->Presupuesto->getInsertID();
                            $presupuesto_detalle['articulo_id'] = $articulo['articulo_id'];
                            $presupuesto_detalle['cantidad'] = $articulo['cantidad'];
                            $presupuesto_detalle['monto'] = $articulo['monto'];
                            $presupuesto_detalle['descuento'] = $articulo['descuento'];
                            $presupuesto_detalle['familia_id'] = $this->Articulo->field( 'familias_id', array( 'id' => $articulo['articulo_id'] ) );
                            $presupuesto_detalle['categoria_id'] = $this->Familia->field( 'categoria_id', array( 'id' => $presupuesto_detalle['familia_id'] ) );

                            $detalle_guardado = $this->PresupuestoDetalle->save( $presupuesto_detalle );

                }                    
}else{
                                            $detalle_guardado = false;
                                        }
                        if ( $detalle_guardado ) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash( 'El presupuesto se creó satisfactoriamente.', 'messages/green' );
                                                    echo json_encode($this->Session); die();    
                            if ( $cliente_id != '0' ) {
                                $this->redirect( '/Presupuestos/edit/' . $cliente_id . '#tab_presupuestos' );
                            }
                            else {
                                $this->redirect( '/Presupuestos/index' );
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash( 'No se pudo guardar el detalle del presupuesto. Por favor revise los datos.', 'messages/red');
                                                    $this->redirect( '/Presupuestos/add/0'  );
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('No se pudo guardar el presupuesto. Por favor revise los datos.', 'messages/red');
                                            $this->redirect( '/Presupuestos/add/0'  );                                        
                                    }
                }
                else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('No se pudo guardar la información de relevamiento. Por favor revise los datos.', 'messages/red');
                                    $this->redirect( '/Presupuestos/add/0' );                                
                            }
    }
```

But I'm defining PresupuestoDetalle. This is what I'm using to create an input, so I think It should pass as PresupuestoDetalle to the controller...

```
<?php 
            echo $this->Form->input( 'PresupuestoDetalle.' . $detalle['index'] . '.cantidad',
                    array( 
                        'label' => false,
                        'div' => 'input text',
                        'class' => 'easyui-numberbox cantidad',
                        'data-options' => $numberbox_dataoptions,
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'style' => 'width: 60px;',
                        'value' => isset( $detalle['valor'] ) ? $detalle['valor']['cantidad'] : ''
                    )); 
            ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i too know nothing of cakephp...i however would consider using `$_SESSION` here. if you redirect it is a different request, therefore you lose state. remember to delete 'no longer needed' data in `$_SESSION`

Comment: So I should just write it in session?

Answer (score 1):

User

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

it redirect to previous page